# re-indexing duplicate rows

Tags: sql, indexing, duplicates, ms-access-2010

Hi I have a table below;

```
ID  length
1   1050
1   1000
1   900
1   600
2   545
2   434
3   45
3   7
4   5
```

I need an SQL code to make the below table

```
ID  IDK length
1   1   1050
1   2   1000
1   3   900
1   4   600
2   1   545
2   2   434
3   1   45
3   2   7
4   1   5
```

IDK is the new column to reindexing the same ID according to ascending order of length.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

This is a pain in MS Access.  Here is one way using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from foo as t2
        where t2.id = t.id and t2.length >= t.length
       ) as idk
from foo as t;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff I change the table name as foo 
select foo.*,
       (select count(*)
        from foo as t2
        where t2.id = t1.id and t2.length >=t1.length
       ) as idk
from foo;
but all the IDK results is 0

Comment: select foo.*,
       (select count(*)
        from foo as t2
        where t2.ID = foo.ID and t2.length >=foo.length
       ) as IDK
from foo;
the code is working. but how can I sortted the table according to the length descending order within the same ID